# Rendering view, but no object in gsp

Tags: grails, render, gsp

I try to render a view, which works fine, but it doesn't seem to get the model object I pass along to it. I can't figure out the reason, as this should be very straightforward according to all manuals and examples.

Model object

```
class Race {

    def distance = "1/4 mile"
    def racer1
    def racer2
}
```

`RaceController` renders here

```
def doFullRace(Race race) {

            render (view: 'raceProgress', model: [race: race])
        }
```

and `raceProgress.gsp` should display it easily enough

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <div id="raceStart" align="center">
...
            <p>${race.racer1} is racing ${race.distance} against ${race.racer2}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

but I instead I get this
[image: object not found]

Any ideas on what basic thing I missed?

Comment: racer1 is null object, unsure why your classes have defined objects as def - if you add `<p>${race?.racer1} is racing ${race?.distance} against ${race?.racer2}</p>` the null point exception will go away but you will still have no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following:

```
def doFullRace(Race race) {
    render (view: 'raceProgress', model: [race: race])
}
```

One of the ways for `race` to be `null` there is if all of the following are true:

- `Race` is a domain class
- The request submitted to `doFullRace` includes a request parameter named `id`
- There is no record in the database with an `id` that matches `params.id`

From http://docs.grails.org/3.3.9/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects...

> If the command object’s type is that of a domain class and there is an
>   id request parameter then instead of invoking the domain class
>   constructor to create a new instance a call will be made to the static
>   get method on the domain class and the value of the id parameter will
>   be passed as an argument.

And...

> If the command object’s type is a domain class and there is no id
>   request parameter or there is an id request parameter and its value is
>   empty then null will be passed into the controller action unless the
>   HTTP request method is "POST", in which case a new instance of the
>   domain class will be created by invoking the domain class constructor.
>   For all of the cases where the domain class instance is non-null, data
>   binding is only performed if the HTTP request method is "POST", "PUT"
>   or "PATCH".

Comment: That's an excellent response! However, as it turns out, it wasn't that complicated. I was rendering the same view twice, once without the model object.